# OpenCV Video Write-out Size is Reduced

Tags: python, opencv, video-editing

I am trying to combine frames into a video using openCV, using the following codes. However, the total size of frames in png format is over 500 megabytes, yet the output video is only 360 kilobytes. 
How can I write out the video without any compression?

```
#setting fourcc
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
#creating the writer object
writer=cv2.VideoWriter('Screen1.avi', fourcc, 30, (unitWidth, unitHeight), True)
#writing out the frames into video
for i in range(Frames):
    img=cv2.imread('./Screen1/frame'+str(i)+'.png')
    writer.write(img)
writer.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are worrying about video quality, try a lossless codec like the Huffman Lossless Codec.

`fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'HFYU')`

Or search for any other lossless codec.

If you want absolutely no compression at all, you can try `fourcc = 0`, which will output every frame raw and result in very large file size.